# How to identify an unknown LCD pins from scrap, and use it for Arduino

Tags: lcd, pins

I've got an unknown LCD from scrap, I don't know what each pin is.

can anyone help me with this?
it has 19 pins that 16 are functional.

also when I touch each pin with hot solder some signs turn on.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Just buy a new one is my advice.

Comment: There's thousands upon thousands of different displays out there. Reverse-engineering without knowing the brand is a complete waste of time. Instead fork up a few dollars to buy one with actual documentation in the form of a datasheet.

Comment: Buy a new LCD is not a problem, I want to know the reverse engineering path though. If it's possible

Comment: Chances are the four pins on left are the common terminals and the other 12 are the segment terminals. Basically you need a LCD driver chip or a MCU with built-in LCD driver to control it.

Comment: if you found a similar device that still works . . .